# Getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:356)

Tags: java, jexcelapi

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class SpreadsheetRead {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws BiffException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("Book1.xls"));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);

        Cell name = sheet.getCell(0, 0);
        Cell name1 = sheet.getCell(1, 0);
        try {
            Cell name2 = sheet.getCell(2, 0);
            Cell name3 = sheet.getCell(3, 0);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Cell value = sheet.getCell(0, 1);
        Cell value1 = sheet.getCell(1, 1);
        Cell value2 = sheet.getCell(2, 1);
        Cell value3 = sheet.getCell(3, 1);

        System.out.println(sheet.getRows());
        System.out.println(sheet.getColumns());
        System.out.println(name.getContents());
        System.out.println(name1.getContents());
        System.out.println(value.getContents());
        System.out.println(value1.getContents());
    }
}
```

Excel Sheet Content (Book1.xls) ... It Contains 4 Rows and 2 Columns as mentioned below.

```
Name Value
A    1
B    2
C    3
```

This code is working for cell [(0,0),(0,1),(1,0) & (1,1)] and for rest of the cells it is giving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException... please help

#### Stack Trace

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
4
2
Name
Value
A
    at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:356)
    at SpreadsheetRead.main(SpreadsheetRead.java:25)
1
```

Comment: which line is 25? Most likely you're trying to get a cell that doesn't exist

Comment: Line 25 is where I am trying to access Cell (2,0) but you can see the excel it has row2 and column 1.. just after try block

Comment: I think you mixed up the row and column coordinates. The fact that the stack trace is mixed with the logging output is unfortunate, however, and I don't know why 2,1 and 3,1 didn't fail

Comment: they are also failed it just that I commented those lines when I executed this code.

Comment: then you surely mixed up your coordinates. try with `Cell(0,0)`..`Cell(0,3)`

Comment: but I don't have column 4 ... I've also given the example of my spreadsheet. please refer it.

Comment: that is also not working... :(

Comment: I got the answer... in JExcelAPI rows and columns are interchanged... Cell (0,3) means 0th column and 3rd row.

Comment: Isn't this what I've been trying to tell you?

Comment: yes... you were saying correct ... but I was not getting it earlier.. this is the same you told me earlier... thanks a lot !!! :)

Comment: you can write the same in your answer as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console output is slightly tangled up; data logged to `System.err` overlap those logged to `System.out`:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
4
2
Name
Value
A
    at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:356)
    at SpreadsheetRead.main(SpreadsheetRead.java:25)
1
```

Let's untangle those, and match them with the respective logging calls:

Error log:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:356)
    at SpreadsheetRead.main(SpreadsheetRead.java:25)
```

> Line 25 is where I am trying to access Cell (2,0)

this indicates that Cell(2,0) is not in the table.

Let's look at the System.out log.

> they are also failed it just that I commented those lines when I executed this code.

I assume you mean the access to column 1 and the respective logging calls.

```
Cell name = sheet.getCell(0, 0);
Cell name1 = sheet.getCell(1, 0);
Cell value = sheet.getCell(0, 1);
Cell value1 = sheet.getCell(1, 1);

System.out.println(sheet.getRows());      //4
System.out.println(sheet.getColumns());   //2
System.out.println(name.getContents());   //Name
System.out.println(name1.getContents());  //Value
System.out.println(value.getContents());  //A
System.out.println(value1.getContents()); //1
```

Comparing this to the table:

```
Name Value
A    1
B    2
C    3
```

indicates that the first argument is the column index, not row index as you seem to expect.

[the `Sheet#getCell` documentation](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Sheet.html#getCell%28int,%20int%29) confirms this:

> ```
> public Cell getCell(int column,
>                     int row)
> ```